# asp.net app unable to run pscp on IIS while working in VS

Tags: asp.net, iis, putty, pscp

I have functionality in an ASP.NET application that runs a cmd process that uses PSCP.EXE (Putty) to copy a file from an external Linux server to the local server. When I run the ASP.NET application interactively by using the Run command in Visual Studio 2010 it works fine. However, when I deploy the application to IIS (on the same server!) and try to run it I get an error coming back from the PSCP.EXE command line. The error is this:

Fatal: Network error: Connection timed out

Does anyone know why I would get a connection timed out error when running the command from IIS 7 on my box, but when I run it through Visual Studio on the same box it works fine?